# Statement inside If block executing even when condition is false

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

```
@model Portal.Models.MessageModel

<link href="~/Content/jquery.wysiwyg.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.wysiwyg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/wysiwyg-controls/wysiwyg.image.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/wysiwyg-controls/wysiwyg.link.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/wysiwyg-controls/wysiwyg.table.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/wysiwyg-controls/wysiwyg.cssWrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/wysiwyg-controls/wysiwyg.colorpicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#messagearea').wysiwyg({
                initialContent: function () {
                    var inittext = "";
                    @{if (Model != null)
                       {
                           <text>inittext = '@Model.MessageText';</text>
                       }
                    }
                        return inittext;
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
    <table id="compose-table" style="border-spacing:0 0; max-width: 1200px; min-width: 450px;box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #cfcfcf; width:auto; background-color:white">
        <tbody>
            <tr >
                <td style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #383838;">
                    <form>
                        <div id="destinations" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcfcf; padding: 12px 1px 12px 2px; ">                            

                            **<input name="to" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="false" autocapitalize="false" autocorrect="off" style="padding-left: 8px; background-color:transparent; width:1078px; resize:none; border: none;" placeholder="To" onfocus="displayCCandBCC" value="@Model.From"/>**
                        </div>
                        <div id="addressdiv" style="display: none">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr id="cc" style="display: none"></tr>
                                    <tr id="bcc" style="display: none"></tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div id="subjectdiv" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcfcf; padding : 12px 1px 12px 2px; ">
                        @{if (Model == null){
                            <input name="subject" style="padding-left: 8px; width: 1078px; border: none; background-color: inherit" placeholder="Subject" />
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            <input name="subject" style="padding-left: 8px; width: 1078px; border: none; background-color: inherit" placeholder="Subject" value="@String.Concat("re: ", Model.Subject)" />
                          }
}
                        </div>
                        <textarea id="messagearea" style="min-height:300px; width:100%; padding:0 0 0 0"></textarea>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

This script is in a cshtml razor view, coming into the view Model is null, but I get a null reference exception:

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Source Error: 

Line 20:       {
Line 21:           Response.Write("inittext = '@Model.MessageText';");
Line 22:       }
Line 23:       return inittext;
Line 24:   }
```

> Source File:  d:\Projects\Patient Portal\Portal.MVC\Views\Message\Compose.cshtml    Line:  22

Why is the response.write still being executed even though the if condition is false, and why does the exception point to line 22 and not line 21?

Comment: Errors generally point to the line after, or the line which takes the code out of scope.

Comment: Don't you need to remove the "@" before "Model"?

Comment: @David I've done it both ways, makes no difference

Comment: Finally found it by chopping large chunks of code out, it was on the <input..../> button, there was an unchecked reference to @Model.From that was causing the error, completely not where the error message was indicating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have MVC5 to test this, but I think your `Response` object is null, you should be creating your dynamic javascript like this instead:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    <text>inittext = '@Model.MessageText';</text>
}
```

Also, make sure `Model.MessageText` is escaped properly so that it's contents don't cause a javascript error.

Comment: I initially had that and changed it to response because I thought maybe something weird was going on with the <text>...</text> tag.

Comment: If that's the case, then your error is someplace else.  Do you have the correct `@model` declaration at the top of the cshtml file?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a JS code block, you need to use the explicit CSHTML opening tags to do your if.

Comment: I tried wrapping it in `@{...}` and that did nothing to help.

Comment: You might have to store it into a variable at the beginning of your JS script block... I remember having to do something like this because the Razor interpreter gets confused...